# Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError store/print.css isn't precompiled - what to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, apache, capistrano, spree

I updated my Spree Commerce app to include the spree_fancy theme (which works locally) and after pushing the changes to git and running cap deploy the page now displays the error message "we're sorry but something went wrong".

I looked in the production.log file but all I see are lists and lists of rendered stuff and no errors. Only 200 OK and 301 moved permanently messages.

I rebooted the server and did `rake db:migrate`. Both did not help.

How do I go about finding what went wrong?

//UPDATE

I've added I've added   `config.consider_all_requests_local       = true` to production.rb, did a rollback and a deploy and now I see an error message in the browser (this is not in the production.log...):

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in    
Spree/home#index 

store/print.css isn't precompiled
```

I searched the internet and added the following to production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( store/shared/_print.css )
```

but this did not help. I also added the print.css file to /public/assets/stylesheets/store/ and precompiled with `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` but that did not work either.

Does anyone have another idea what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile. Thanks!